# React Native function being called before onPress

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement google login using firebase and before I even press google button, google sign in function is being called, I can't understand what I did wrong

As soon as I press the button that redirects to registration page, a pop up for google login appears

1 - user choose a user type (tourist, touristic guide)

```
const TipoUsuario = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function redirecionarRegistro(tipoUsuario) {
    navigation.navigate('Registro', { tipoUsuario })
  }

  function redirecionarLogin() {
    navigation.navigate('Login')
  }
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titulo}>
        <Text>O que você quer fazer?</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => redirecionarRegistro(1)}>
        <View style={styles.subcontainer}>
          <Text style={styles.texto}>Sou turista e quero ir a eventos</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => redirecionarRegistro(2)}>
        <View style={styles.subcontainer}>
          <Text style={styles.texto}>
            Sou guia turístico e quero cadastrar meus eventos
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={redirecionarLogin}>
        <View style={styles.subcontainer}>
          <Text style={styles.texto}>Já tenho uma conta, me deixe entrar</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

2 - Goes to registration page, where user can choose how to register

**Google login appears when this component renders**

```
const Registro = ({ route }) => {

    const { tipoUsuario } = route.params;

    //console.log(tipoUsuario)

    return (
        <>
        <AcessoFormulario tipoUsuario={tipoUsuario} />
        <LoginSocial />
        </>
    )
}

export default Registro;
```

3. Login Social component - Google login should appear only if google button was pressed

   const LoginSocial = () => {

   ```
      const { logado, usuario, loginGoogle } = useAuth();


      // function onGoogleButtonPress() {
      //   loginGoogle()
      //   //console.log('qando sou chamado')
      // }

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {/* // Facebook */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.buttonContainer, { backgroundColor: "#dae2f1" }]}
          >
            <View style={styles.iconeContainer}>
              <Ionicons name={"logo-facebook"} size={30} color={"#385898"} />
            </View>
            <Text style={[styles.botaoTexto, { color: "#385898" }]}>
              Entrar com Facebook
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {/* // Google */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={loginGoogle()}
            style={[styles.buttonContainer, { backgroundColor: "#f7d7d4" }]}
          >
            <View style={styles.iconeContainer}>
              <Ionicons name={"logo-google"} size={30} color={"#DB4437"} />
            </View>
            <Text style={[styles.botaoTexto, { color: "#DB4437" }]}>
              Entrar com Google
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    };



    export default LoginSocial;
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function here, instead, pass the name:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={loginGoogle}
  style={[styles.buttonContainer, { backgroundColor: "#f7d7d4" }]}
>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => loginGoogle()}
  style={[styles.buttonContainer, { backgroundColor: "#f7d7d4" }]}
>
```

Comment: dumb me, thank you